# Use hashtag (#) in tweepy to post a tweet

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy, hashtag

I have a running Tweepy installation to automatically post tweets.
I want to make use of (#) hashtags in an post, how i do that.

I'm looking for some code to post an tweet with an hashtag. 
Simple use of # in the post doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. I also found that tweepy will allow you to post a piece of text, or a variable but not a combination of the two.  The workaround is to create a variable containing all the text you wish to tweet and include that in the output line.

```
someVar = "Tweet this with a #hashtag"
api = tp.API(auth)
api.update_status(someVar)
```